# How to prevent form submission during client side validation using infragistics control?

Tags: javascript, submit, client-side, infragistics

I have an `infragistics` `webimagebutton` with `clientside` `click` `event`

```
<igtxt:webimagebutton id="btnOwnerSave" runat="server" cssclass="bodytext" text="Save"
     usebrowserdefaults="False">
      <clientsideevents click="confirm_ssn"></clientsideevents>
</igtxt:webimagebutton>
```

I have a function that handles that event. This function displays `confirmation dialog`.
Now, when I click "CANCEL" button, `postback` happens. I do not want execution go back to the server. I just need it to stop as soon as user clicks "CANCEL", just as it can be done with regular `javascript: return functionName()`

This is my function:

```
function confirm_ssn()
{
    var butPress;
    var strMessage;

    strMessage = "";
    if (ss# is not valid)
    {
        strMessage = "There is a SSN starting with 9 \nClick OK to proceed, click Cancel to make change ";
        butPress = confirm(strMessage); 
        if (butPress)
        {
           do something;
        }
         else 
        {
           stop submitting the form;
           return;
        }
    }

    confirm_own_percentage();
    return;
}


function confirm_own_percentage()
{
    var percentageOwned = 0;
    var ownerper = document.getElementById("txtOwnerPercentageOwned").value;
    var secondownerper = document.getElementById("txtSecondOwnerPercentageOwned").value;
    var butPress;
    var strMessage; 

    if(!isNaN(ownerper))
    {
        percentageOwned = percentageOwned + parseInt(ownerper);
        if(!isNaN(secondownerper))
        {
            percentageOwned = percentageOwned + parseInt(secondownerper);
        }
    }

    if(percentageOwned < 50)
    {
        strMessage = "The % Equity Ownership is not equal or greater than 50%\nClick OK to proceed, click cancel to make change "
        butPress = confirm(strMessage); 
        if (butPress)
        {
          do something;
        }
        else 
        {
          stop submitting the form;
        }           
    }       
}
```

What can be done to achieve that?

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to this question. Hole it will be helpful to someone in the future.

Basically, when using `Infragistics`'s `clientsideevent`, this event receives references to an object it is used on and an event to be fired, for example, in my case, I just need to add these references in my parameter list:

```
function confirm_ssn(oButton, oEvent)
```

Then, in order to prevent form submission I need to use `oEvent.cancel = true` when I click "CANCEL" button on a confirmation dialog.

This will do the trick.

Hope it will help someone